# What are the rules governing approval or rejection of edits?

Tags: support

Several times when editing recently I've seen bad edits that have attracted several reject votes yet, when I've clicked to reject them, I've had a message that the edit has already been approved.

It made me wonder - what are the actual rules that determine whether an edit gets approved or rejected? In terms of the number of votes, and suchlike.

Comment: You can always later go back to that review and look how people voted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, an edit gets approved if it reaches 3 approve votes, and it gets rejected if it reaches 3 reject votes. If there are contradicting votes, the number of votes does not change.

On other Stack Exchange sites, the number of votes is not 3, but 2.

Comment: Thanks. I presume there has been extensive discussion about the possibility of edits that have attracted reject votes needing additional accept votes? Seems like it might be a good idea to me :)

Comment: @MattThrower There has been a discussion about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561/229438

Comment: I may be cynical, but I feel that requiring more approve votes would just give a few more roboreviewers the badge progress they crave without actually changing the outcomes.

Comment: @Wooble That's true indeed. Then it would be better to bounce approve votes with a reject vote instead of just requiring more approve votes.